# Rollback data liquibase.exception.RollbackFailedException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Referential integrity constraint violation:

Tags: liquibase

I try to roll back data after test runnining using:

```
delete from instance;
delete from workspace;
```

however I receive:

```
liquibase.exception.RollbackFailedException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Referential integrity constraint violation: 
"FK_INSTANCE_ID: PUBLIC.WORKSPACE FOREIGN KEY(INSTANCE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.INSTANCE(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
```

I figured out that it is caused by required relation beetween tables. How to force deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify what database platform you are using, and the answer might differ depending on that. In general though, you need to either use a 'cascade' with delete, or else delete the relationships before deleting the tables.